# Continuous function from $[0,1]$ to set of idempotent matrices in $M_2(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: general-topology, matrices, continuity, metric-spaces, idempotents

How to prove that there exists no continuous function $f:[0,1] \to \{A \in M_2(\mathbb{R})|A^2=A\}$ such that $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=I$.

Comment: hint: can you compose $f$ with a (continuous) function on matrices which is integer valued on idempotents (there are at least two natural choices)? The composition will be a continuous map from $[0,1] \to \mathbb{Z}$ and is therefore constant. So long as this function outputs different values for the zero matrix and the identity, this will guarantee no such $f$ exists. Fun fact: one choice of the function allows you to immediately generalize the claim to $A^n = A$ instead of $A^2 = A$ for any positive integer $n$.

Comment: Got it! Thank you. I took the function as determinant. @J.Loreaux

Comment: you should turn your solution into an answer.

Answer (score 6):

Consider $g : \{ A \in M_2(\mathbb{R})| A^2=A\} \to \{0,1\}$ given by $g(A)=detA$. Then $g\circ f$ is a continuous function from $[0,1] \to \{0,1\}$ . Then $g(0)=0$ and $g(1)=1$. So, $g$ is surjective. Now $[0,1]$ is connected but $\{0,1\}$ is not connected. Hence such f does not exist.

Comment: Determinant haters may consider $h:t\mapsto\operatorname{trace}(f(t))$ instead. Since $f$ is continuous and $f(t)$ is idempotent, $h$ is an integer-valued continuous function on a connected set $[0,1]$. Hence it must be constant. However, the conditions $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=I_2$ imply that $h(0)=0\ne 2=h(1)$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Yes, the trace was the other natural function I was considering. However, using the determinant, you can expand the set in question to $\{ A \in M_2(\mathbb{R}) \mid \exists n \in \mathbb{N}, A^n = A \}$ since the determinant values of these matrices still form a totally disconnected set, and hence every continuous function from $[0,1]$ into this set is constant.